# Make query to select specific columns for specific date

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am having trouble in displaying right result when run query.

My table is organized this way TIME - timestamp

```
ID    |    TIME      |      USERID  |    ACTIONS
1        1483302364           1             3
2        1483225201           2             3
3        1483311599           1             3
4        1483272464           3             4
5        1483291052           4             3             
6        1483274125           1             3
7        1483304974           1             3
```

I am trying to make a query where I will select all actions for one day.
Let's say I want to select all actions that happened on 02/28/2017.

I do not know is it possible to make a query that will display all actions that happened on mentioned day no matter time

Answer (score 1):

Use DATE() and FROM_UNIXTIME() together.

```
select id, date(FROM_UNIXTIME(rtime)), userid, actions
from uttime
WHERE rtime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') + 86400;
```

Check it: http://rextester.com/OUZIM16796

Thanks to @Strawberry for his advice about the use or WHERE clause in this way, and for adding an `INDEX(rtime)` just to improve performance.

Comment: Note that on an indexed table [`INDEX(rtime)`], reversing the WHERE logic will dramtically improve performance... so `WHERE rtime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') + 86400;`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Strawberry, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE()` function to compare `day`

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
Where DATE( timeCol ) = '2017-02-28'
```

Or you can use `hour:min` for comparing timestamps:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
Where timeCol BEtWEEN "2017-02-28 00:00:00" AND "2017-02-28 23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME)`,try this:

```
select * from table1 where select DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME))='2017-28-02'
```